# aggregate and plotting histograms with the same scale and axes

Tags: r, visualization, aggregate, histogram, distribution

I have data named PACKS like this:

```
error    CENTRE_B
    -13  1104
    -13  1303
    -13  1303
    2    1204
    2    1403
    2    1403
    2    1403
    2    1502
    3    1503
```

My aim is to compare distributions. I want to to plot histograms for errors for each value of CENTRE_B. The problem is that the histograms have to be in the same scale.

I tried this:

```
new.par <- par(mfrow=c(5, 5))
histograms = aggregate(error ~ CENTRE_B, PACKS, hist)
```

This plots histograms. However, I don't know how to deliver additional argument to hist in aggregate (breaks = c(-80,80)).

Another problem with this is that histograms seems to be data.table of dimension 2x45, so it does not contain histograms. So I don't know how to make changing parameters automatic.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: You have 3 columns and 2 headers. What is the third header?

Comment: It didn't metter, now there are only two columns. Thanks for this comment.

Comment: Yes, there were row names.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about `aggregate`. Just use `split` and do a simple for loop. Then you can input all args right into `hist`.

```
new=split(PACKS$error,PACKS$CENTRE_B)
for(i in 1:length(new))
hist(new[[i]],main="Some fancy title", sub="don't forget you can use paste to change the title between loops")
```

Comment: Is there a way to plot only one histogram that contains all of there sub-histograms?

Comment: @MohanadKaleia There are several ways to plot multiple graphs on the same page by splitting the plotting region into multiple subplots if thats what you mean. You could I suppose represent each hist with a line/bellcurve and put them all on the same graph. You could also just put them all on one hist and color code them. It might make more sense to use a bar plot for this and use stacking bars because some groups over lap in this example. Lots of options.